# Date.getTime in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, date

Here is my code to assign a value to the Date:

```
long saveddatevalue = new Date().getTime();
```

I just want to know, what does this saved long variable actually show? I wish to use this to output values within a certain number of days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It will basically give you the same result as `System.currentTimeMillis()` - the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch of midnight January 1st 1970, UTC.

Comment: That's what I use for my android apps.

Comment: Therefore, if I was to work out the number of milliseconds in 32 days (2,764,800,000) seconds, minus that from the value at "new Date().getTime();", then reference a new Date.getTime at the time of outputting the results, I should be able to only output the results in the past 32 days?

Comment: @AndyMarkTingey: It's not really clear what you mean by "reference a new Date.getTime at the time of outputting the results". I would personally use `System.currentTimeMillis()` in preference to constructing a `Date` *just* to get the current millisecond value - but then I'd personally use some sort of `Clock` interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is far easier to work with [`java.util.Calendar.add(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for manipulating dates. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-date-time-date-manipulation-java/) is some sample code.